# Gaussian Mixture Model for face verification

Tags: confidence-interval, matlab

I try to implement MSR Identity Toolkit for Matlab that build mainly for speaker verification. [This toolkit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52279) refer to this paper titled [Speaker Veriﬁcation Using Adapted Gaussian Mixture Models](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~turnbull/cs97/f09/paper/reynolds00.pdf) . I'm using Pseudo Zernike Moments to extract features (363x1 per image). I try varied the mixture, however found that the EER is lower when set to 1 (EER=40%). However I don't quite understand how it perform the last process where the score of likelihood is calculated among trials data and models data.

In the given Matlab script, `score_gmm_trials`, the score of each trial data is calculated by

```
likelihood_score(trial_number) = mean(GMM_posteriorprobability-UBM_posterior_probability);
```

1. What is the score referred to?
2. How to determine the threshold value to define reject and accept values?
3. How to test the model if data is not labelled as known or unknown?
4. How to read the result in order to know if what I'd implement is correct or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The score you mentioned (likelihood_score) is the log-likelihood ratio depicted in equation (2) from the paper.
2. As far as I know, finding the optimal threshold is up to the system designer because it may vary depending on the application. So it would be good for you to draw a DET curve using the compute_eer function with showfig option, and see how your system operates on various thresholds.
3. You need a labeled trial dataset to compute the false alarm rate (FAR) or the false reject rate (FRR) which are needed to obtain the DET curve.
4. A system with lower EER is usually considered to have better performance. Therefore if the DET curve is closer to the origin, it means that the general performance of your system is relatively good.

Although it seems like you are dealing with an image dataset, since you're using the MSR Identity Toolkit, I'd like to recommend you the following paper:
J. Hansen and T. Hasan, "Speaker recognition by machines and humans," IEEE Signal Processing Magazine, vol. 2015, no. 6, pp. 74--99, 2015.
This paper kindly explains about the general flow of the speaker recognition process and some famous algorithms and performance measures used in this field.

Hope this helped you!